# Chrome HTML5 notifications displaying white font on white background

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, gtk, html5

When filling an input with the wrong type or pattern and hitting "submit", Chrome displays notifications as shown below:

[image: Correct]

The thing is, I'm using a theme with a dark background on my system, so the default font is white (or close to it). For some reason Chrome uses that font on those notifications, resulting in the following:

[image: Wrong]

I tried changing `Use GTK+ Theme` to `Use Classic Theme` on `chrome://settings`, but the problem persisted. The only way to "solve" it was changing to a theme with a clear background (on my system, not on the browser).

Is there any workaround to it?

I'm currently using Chromium `Version 31.0.1650.63 Built on Debian 7.2, running on Debian 7.3 (238485)`.

Comment: Try submitting the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: Do you have an example page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browsers allow styling of validation bubbles using the 
[`-webkit-validation-bubble*`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-inline-bubbles) CSS styles.

However, since Chrome moved away from WebKit to [Blink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_%28layout_engine%29), this was removed.
See for example
[Issue 259050: ::-webkit-validation-bubble stopped working in Chrome Blink](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050).

Your only option now is to override the general validation bubble mechanism
and issue your own message.

In a form, you can use the [novalidate attribute](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/11-novalidate.html) and do your own client-side validation in the Submit button:

**HTML**

```
<form novalidate> ... </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('invalid', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Possibly implement your own here.
    }, true);
}
```

A nice article about form validation is
[Constraint Validation: Native Client Side Validation for Web Forms](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/).

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping I could fix this locally (i.e. on my browser only, not having to change the website's code) so I'll leave the question unanswered for a little longer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do this on the browser side only is to use a User Stylesheet.  On Ubuntu (based on Debian), the file you want should be stored here:

```
$HOME/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

You'll have to use the Developer Tools to use the Inspect Element option to find out the exact CSS styling element to override and then set "color: black !important;" on it in the file above.

As a simple example to illustrate, you can add something like:

```
body { color: green !important; }
```

to the `custom.css` file and save it to see the effect (which is immediate) on all text on any web page with a <kbd>body</kbd> element (which is basically any site page).

Comment: Unfortunately the validation bubbles are not stylable.

Comment: Then that probably means modifying Chromium source to modify the internal stylesheet for the bubbles..  :-/

Comment: Do that, and many people will love you dearly.